# How php requires a class inside a class function?

Tags: php, class, php-5.4

I have a class:

```
class Test {

 public function someFunction()
 {

    require('SomeOtherClass.php');

 }


}
```

I can't understand how php requires the class here if another class physically can't be inside a function of a class? how php does this? where php puts the class then?

Comment: Why can't another class "physically" be inside a function of a class?

Comment: @Popnoodles I mean that you can't define a class inside a function in the code editor isn't it?, cause I've never seen a class inside a function o_O

Comment: it's about the `scope`

Comment: so if I require it in a class function, will other classes see this requireded class?

Comment: Yes but only after it's been required.

Comment: I suspect that this code is due to a misunderstanding. I cannot think of 'use case' for this as it will not be very maintainable. for example, you cannot run 'Test->someFunction()' twice as it will fail with already defined 'SomeotherClass'. Basically, all class definitions should be considered 'global' or namespace scope and 'included' accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly valid code:

```
function foo() {
    class Foobar {
        function speak() {
            echo "Hi";
        }
    }
    $obj = new Foobar();
    $obj->speak();
}
// $obj = new Foobar(); // Will fail, as Foobar will be defined the global scope when running foo();
foo();
$obj = new Foobar(); // Will be OK, now the class is defined in the global scope
//foo(); // Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Foobar
```

The output is:

```
Hi
```

For details see [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

Comment: $obj = new \Foobar(); works fine on PHP 5.3 after foo() has run, as all classes are defined in 'global' or namespace scope. This issue is not as 'straight-forward' as it first appears. It is more about 'compile time' vs 'runtime'. And then 'compiling' other stuff later.

Comment: Thank you for your note I was too hasty when applying "scope rule" on classes as well... which is unfortunately not true. I fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

This is in the documentation for [`include`](http://php.net/include):

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. **However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.** *(emphasis added)*

`require` is identical to `include` in virtually all respects, including this one.

Comment: would it help to emphasize about functions and classes always having global scope?

Comment: @RyanVincent Since you asked so nicely ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following in the class:

```
class Test {
    public $other_class;

    function __construct() {
        $this->other_class = new other_class();
    }

    public function someFunction() {
        $this->other_class;
    }
}
```

To use this. Inlcude your classes like this:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    include_once 'classes/'.$class.'.php';
});
```

Use that function in a file that is included everywhere